# Central alignment of responsive boxes

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm struggling to create responsive pods (boxes) which effectively stack and centre align. Have successfully got the boxes to stack but can't successfully apply central alignment. Need the boxes to centre align as opposed to current left alignment:

Current code:

```
.container {
    width:100%;
    height:600px;
}

.content {
    float:left;
    height:275px;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right:10px;
}

.content1 {
    width:300px;
    padding:10px;
    margin-top:20px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204);
}

.content2 {
    width:300px;
    padding:10px;
    margin-top:20px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204);
}
```

---

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="content1 content">
        <h2>Box 1</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur vitae risus semper, faucibus nulla vitae, vulputate ante. Fusce non erat eu metus pellentesque suscipit facilisis ut dolor.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="content2 content">
        <h2>Box 2</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur vitae risus semper, faucibus nulla vitae, vulputate ante. Fusce non erat eu metus pellentesque suscipit facilisis ut dolor.</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

All help much appreciated!

Comment: You need the both boxes to be centred together ? @Chris

Comment: @Riot Zeast Captain I do, require both boxes to centre align even when screen size is reduced. Currently they left align when screen size is significantly reduced.

Answer (score 1):

Lots can be done to improve the overall structure and code readability, but to answer your question, add `text-align: center;` to your `.container` class and replace floating of the `.content` with `display: inline-block;`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    .fullbox{
        margin: 0 auto;
        display: table;
    }
    .container {
        width:100%; 
    }

    .content {
        float:left;
        height:275px;
        margin-left:10px;
        margin-right:10px;
    }

    .content1 {
        width:300px;
        padding:10px;
        margin-top:20px;
        border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204);
    }

    .content2 {
        width:300px;
        padding:10px;
        margin-top:20px;
        border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204);
    }
    <div class="fullbox">
      <div class="container">
          <div class="content1 content">
              <h2>Box 1</h2>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur vitae risus semper, faucibus nulla vitae, vulputate ante. Fusce non erat eu metus pellentesque suscipit facilisis ut dolor.</p>
          </div>

          <div class="content2 content">
              <h2>Box 2</h2>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur vitae risus semper, faucibus nulla vitae, vulputate ante. Fusce non erat eu metus pellentesque suscipit facilisis ut dolor.</p>
          </div>

      </div>
    </div>
```

I   if it is in that case, you should write @media-Query as displayed below,
    Just add this code, 
     
    `@media (max-width: 767px) {
        .content {
            float: none;
        }
    }`

```
or updated fiddle link here, [Link][1]


  [1]: https://jsfiddle.net/zeasts/ynyybte7/1/
```

Comment: The two boxes now centre align correctly at max screen size. However when screen size is reduced the boxes stack, left aligned. Can't see the above required code change in the above example? Is what I am wanting to achieve possible with pure HTML / CSS?

Comment: @Chris Check the updated fiddle or add media-query as displayed above.